# how to call another program from PHP

Tags: php

Is there anyone out there that has a method or an example of calling another program from PHP?

I have this project that a client is using a Delphi program and I'm  writing a PHP script that requires me to communicate with the program.

Comment: Delphi is irrelevant. Run it or communicate with it the same as you would with any other program.

Comment: this delphi program is in the same server/pc as the PHP program... so how do i run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use exec to execute an external program (external to php that is).

https://www.php.net/function.exec

You can extract the command line options inside your Delphi application using the
`ParamCount` and `ParamStr` functions to extract the command line parameters.